# Specials Menu/Deleting Doubles in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling

I just downloaded Blender 2.82 and when I hit the W key I get the select options and not the specials menu.  Can someone tell me where to access the delete doubles function as I can seem  to find it in any of the menus.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's now called merge by distance under the mesh, cleanup. If you right click it once you see it in the menu, you can add it to a favorites list that comes up when you type Q and select from that pop up each time quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, would never have guessed that. Anyone know of a good reference book or manual that is not as tedious as the Blender Reference Manual.